# Pythonic way to add values to a set within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Lets say i have a dictionary of sets:

```
d = {"foo":{1,2,3},
        "bar":{3,4,5}}
```

Now lets say I want to add the value `7` to the set found within the key `foo`.  This would be easy:

```
d["foo"].add(7)
```

but what if we were unsure of the key already existing?  It doesn't feel very pythonic to check beforehand:

```
if "baz" in dict:
    d["baz"].add(7)
else:
    d["baz"] = {7}
```

I tried to be clever and do something like

```
d["baz"] = set(d["baz"]).add(7)
```

but then you just get a `KeyError` trying to access a bad key in the `set` constructor.

Am i missing something, or do I need to just bite the bullet and look before I leap?  I would understand if that were the case, it would just be neat if there were a simple way to say "Add this value to the set found at this location, or if there isn't a set at that location, make one, and then put it in.

Comment: Would a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) help?

Comment: By the way, you should never shadow the built-in `dict` function. Name your dictionary something else, `dict_` if you must.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for pointing that out, this was just throwaway code that i made just for this question, didn't even think about that.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: if baz in dict , don't need to and should not call .keys

Comment: @JHixson no worries. It seems relatively harmless, but it can lead to pernicious bugs.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks, fixed.

Comment: No worries, in Python 2, calling .keys and not is the difference between a linear scan or O(1)  lookup. In python3 it is an unnecessary function call

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `defaultdict`

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(set)
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {})
>>> d['foo'].add(1)
>>> d['foo'].add(2)
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'foo': {1, 2}})
>>> d['bar'].add(3)
>>> d['bar'].add(4)
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'foo': {1, 2}, 'bar': {3, 4}})
>>>
```

Also, if you must use plain dict, you can use the `.setdefault` method:

```
>>> d2 = {}
>>> d2.setdefault('foo',set()).add(1)
>>> d2.setdefault('foo',set()).add(2)
>>> d2
{'foo': {1, 2}}
>>> d2.setdefault('bar',set()).add(3)
>>> d2.setdefault('bar',set()).add(4)
>>> d2
{'foo': {1, 2}, 'bar': {3, 4}}
>>>
```

### Edit to add time comparisons

You should note that using `defaultdict` is faster:

```
>>> setup = "gen = ((letter,k) for letter in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyx'  for k in range(100)); d = {}"
>>> s = """for l,n in gen:
...     d.setdefault(l,set()).add(n)"""
>>> setup2 = "from collections import defaultdict; gen = ((letter,k) for letter in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyx'  for k in range(100)); d = defaultdict(set)"
>>> s2 = """for l,n in gen:
...     d[l]=n"""
>>> 
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=s, setup=setup, number=10000)
0.005325066005752888
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=s2, setup=setup2, number=10000)
0.0014927469965186901
```

Answer (score 2):

trying to keep this simple, how about this

```
dict['baz'] = dict.get('baz', set())
dict['baz'].add(7)
```

Comment: While the elegance is nice, it does looks like this is basically replicating the functionality of `d.setdefault('baz',set()).add(7)` in two lines

Comment: Ah thanks, yea that is a fair point. If you are doing this type of thing more than once then the defaultdict might server you better as others have suggested.